# Reverse port forwarding to a machine from a machine withing a firewall?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, firewall

So, I have recently been trying to ssh to my home PC from my school's PC, but the problem is the school PC's are behind a strong firewall, I tried using this command:

```
ssh -L (listening port on school PC):localhost:22 (username@Public IP)
```

But it didn't work, I also tried:

```
ssh -R (listening port on school PC):localhost:22 (username@Public IP)
```

But that didn't work either. I'm using Cygwin and I'm pretty sure I installed all ssh packages. I have my modem setup to forward port 22 to port 22 on my PC, so that shouldn't be the issue, I also have set up OpenSSH server correctly. The error I get when trying to connect from the school PC says that the connection timed out.

Comment: If you cannot ssh to your home computer, setting up  a reverse tunnel/port is not going to work as they probably are blocking the protocol.  I would check with your school admin if they are.

Comment: Ok, i'll check with the admins if the protocol is blocked, I was hoping to do it during recess and on my laptop whenever I've finished all of the work assigned in class and to use it to transfer files from my PC if I ever forget some homework on my PC at home so hopefully  they will be ok with me connecting to my home PC.